# PHP MVC где правильно реализовать запрос

Tags: php, mvc

Пишу CMS для своих нужд. Она построена на MVC, есть основные -> контроллер, модель и просмотр (`view`) их (controller model) наследуют уже `index_controller`, `index_model` и так далее.

Вопрос в следующем: на некоторых страницах, к примеру `www.web.com/static` и скажем `www.web.com/newslist`, мне нужно справа выводить список новостей.

Правильно ли будет написать метод выполняющий этот sql запрос в главной модели `model.php` (так как эта модель всегда загружается) и при необходимости выводить список или нужно в модели каждого отдельного контроллера (`static_model.php` и `newslis_model.php`) писать этот метод, ведь получается дублирование кода?!

Comment: Так же советую ознакомиться с Dependency Injection

Answer (score 5):

MVC Отличная идея но упрощенная, неполная и много оставляет для интерпритации. Конкретика сушествует только для вида. До сих пор не могут определиться, где должно быть больше логики в модели или контроллере. Да и в больших приложениях большой кусок логики может логически не принадлежат ни модели, ни контроллеру.

А если по  вопросу то:

1. Суть OOP приложения в том, что каждый **класс выполняет одну функцию** (не путать с `function () {}`).  Поэтому, общий класс не может тянуть новости.
2. В классическом понимании `модель = данные + бизнес логика + валидация` , что в контексте вопроса можно упростить как `модель = данные`.  Значит читать лучше всего в модели новостей.

Пример (за использование статических методов тапочками в меня не кидать).

```
// models/news.php
<?php 

  namespace Models;

  // Class extends and autoloads models/base.php; 
  class News extends Base {
    // 
  }



// controllers/c1.php
<?php 

  namespace Controllers;
  // autoload and include models/news.php
  use Models\News; 

  // Class extends and autoloads controllers/base.php;
  class C1 extends Base {
    public function indexAction($params) {
      // Validation
      $news_list = News::getList($params['smth']);
      //or $news_list = $this->_modelFactory('News', $params['smth']);
      // View
    }
  }


// controllers/c2.php
<?php 

  namespace Controllers;

  // autoload and include models/news.php
  use Models\News; 

  // Class extends and autoloads controllers/base.php;
  class C2 extends Base {
    public function otherAction($params) {
      // Validation
      $news_list = News::getList($params['smth']);
      //or $news_list = $this->_modelFactory('News', $params['smth']);
      // View
    }
  }
```

Comment: Если хотя бы немного углубиться в MVC, то `модель != данные`. Иначе это Anemic Domain Model со всеми вытекающими. Ну и Active Record -- не лучшее решение (хотя и приемлемое в ряде случае).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Полностью согласен. Главное что правильность ответа может меняться от постановки вопроса(деталей). Так же автор не имеет знаний для принятия решения. Поэтому считаю есть смысл упростить ответ, а потом с опытом автор поймет что, где и как.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Поправил ответ. Надеюсь так понятнее и правильнее.

Comment: Да, так стало чуть точнее. Однако валидация - это неотъемлемая часть модели/бизнес-логики (но тут я уже придираюсь =))

Comment: Ввиду недостатка знаний по ООП, я наверное не совсем правильно выразился, я имел в виду что есть основной класс controller а все остальные контроллеры (к примеру контроллер Index) уже погружаются через маршерутиризатор  и расширяют основной контроллер   `class index extends controller`, так же происходит с моделями 'index_model extends model'

Comment: @ConeEnoc Ну на ответ это ни как не влияет. Как надо поделить логику я написал.

Answer (score 2):

не дублирование а модульность т.е. ты должен строить систему так что бы это были отдельные модули. `static_model.php` это к примеру модель таблицы `static` а соответственно `newslis_model.php` это соответственно `newslis` и т.д. после для каждого генериться `view` какой то блок, и в конце из этих блоков составляеться страница.
  Это нужно для того что бы:

> 1. вы могли поменять что то(удалить, отключить) и приложение не разволилось от этого
> 2. вы можете этот блок вывести на любой другой странице